# website search bar doesn't work for python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pageloadstrategy

I would like auto-click the website and search for the information, but somehow the website cannot search, and keep loading. Or just close quickly after it print the key in search bar.

I would like auto-click the website and search for the information, and I tried:

```
import selenium
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import platform
import time
import random
from os import getcwd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-notification")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9230")
#options.add_argument("--headless")
url = 'https://vip.stock.finance.sina.com.cn/mkt/#hs_z'
driver.get(url)
w = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
w.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="inputSuggest"]')))
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="inputSuggest"]').clear()
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="inputSuggest"]').send_keys('sz111973'))
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="SSForm"]/input[3]').click()
```

But somehow the website cannot search, and keep loading. Or just close quickly after it print the key in search bar.
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. to prevent site from very long loading you can use `eager` `pageLoadStrategy`.
2. I see redundant `)` at the end of this line `driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="inputSuggest"]').send_keys('sz111973'))`
   The following code works perfect:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options, desired_capabilities=caps,)
url = 'https://vip.stock.finance.sina.com.cn/mkt/#hs_z'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'inputSuggest')))
input.clear()
input.send_keys('sz111973')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#inputSuggest +input'))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But may I ask why my codes does not work

Comment: I have described that in my answer. Did that resolved your problem?